# Error PLA 1.2 al intentar publicar una aplicacion en ios

Tags: ios, xcode

Estoy tratando de publicar mi aplicación, pero  en la revision me arroja el siguiente error en itunnesconnect :

¿Alguien tiene idea de cual es el motivo del error?

PLA 1.2

The seller and company names associated with your app do not reflect the name “Immer” in the app or its metadata, as required by section 1.2 of the Apple Developer Program License Agreement.

Next Steps

Your app must be published under a seller name and company name that reflects the Immer name. If you have developed this app on behalf of a client, please advise your client to add you to the development team of their Apple Developer account.

Once created, you cannot change your seller name or company name in iTunes Connect. For assistance with changing your company name or seller name, you will need to contact iTunes Connect through the Contact Us page. Select Getting Started from the first dropdown menu, then select General iTunes Connect Inquiry to contact the appropriate iTunes Connect team.

Answer (score 0):

Nunca he tenido ese problema, pero he estado buscando y parece haber diversas opiniones.
[Aquí mencionan algunas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42358022/app-store-binary-rejected-the-seller-and-company-names-associated-with-your-ap/)

Por lo que dicen deberías asegurarte de varias cosas

- El nombre de la aplicación no incluye referencias al nombre de otra aplicación
- El Copyright se corresponde con el nombre del equipo al que pertenece el desarrollador que está tratando de publicar

Si no encuentras una solución es posible que tengas que contactar con Apple para que te expliquen exactamente cual es tu problema